# Sidebar gadget's events do not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html and JavaScript , I have read how to make a gadget in msdn, a good thing to do is to start mastering these languages...

In my js/settings.js I wrote :

System.Gadget.settingsUI = "settings.html";

System.Gadget.onSettingsClosing = SettingsClosing;

```
function SettingsClosing(event)
{
    // Save the settings if the user clicked OK.
    if (event.closeAction == event.Action.commit)
    {
        var e =document.getElementById("HDA");
        System.Gadget.Settings.write("SelectedNumber",e.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
    // Allow the Settings dialog to close.
    event.cancel = false;
}

System.Gadget.onSettingsClosed = SettingsClosed;

function SettingsClosed(event)
{
    // User hits OK on the settings page.
    if (event.closeAction == event.Action.commit)
    {
        userEntry =System.Gadget.Settings.readString("SelectedNumber");
        document.getElementById("text1").value=userEntry;
    }
}
```

and this is the html document:

```
<html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <script language="JavaScript" src="js/settings.js"></script>
        <title>Hijri Date</title>
   <style type="text/css">
       #HDA
      {
        width: 90px;
        font-family: verdana;

      }
  body
        {
            margin: 0;
            width: 130px;
            height:150px;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:green;
            border-radius:5px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="text1"> Hijri Date Adjustment : </p>
        <select name="Hijri Date Adjustment" id="HDA">
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="-1">-1</option>
          <option value="-2">-2</option>
          <option value="-3">-3</option>
</select>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I press the OK button, the settings window does not close, and the paragraph text doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sel.selectedIndex
```

is undefined. You might try

```
e.selectedIndex
```

As soon as JavaScript throws an error, the settings-dialog does not close anymore. This can drive you crazy sometimes ;)